# High beam bulbs burnt out?

Tags: headlight

On my '92 Ford Explorer.. I have no high beams!

This isn't a big deal.. but I'd like to have them if I ever needed them!

The headlights and everything else works fine, but when I turn on the high beams (and see the blue high beam signal light up on my dash), there's no light at all.

Can I replace the bulbs or do I have to replace the entire unit?

What types of these bulbs would I get if I can??

Thanks all!

Answer (score 1):

Your 92 Explorer takes the type 9004 bulb. You should try replacing just one bulb first to see if the high beams come on for that bulb and if so, then replace the other one.

Actually, what you can do is that while wearing gloves, remove one of the bulbs and inspect it. If one of its two filaments (wires) is broken, then definitely a bulb replacement will help. You should wear gloves because the bulbs are very sensitive to skin oils and touching the glass with skin will cause them to fail very soon.